# File associated Icons

Tags: upgrade, files, icons, 21.04, icon-themes

I upgraded ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 21.04, after that some file icons are changed to default icons, I want the icons of the associated files back. How to do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using Gnome as a desktop manager.

Right-click the icon of the file that you wish to change. For example, I right-click the icon of a calc file.

Then, select 'properties' from the drop-down.

Click the icon of the file in the properties window to navigate to the icon of your choice.

Select the icon, and the files thereafter display the icon you have selected.